# Jquery Chosen hides empty optgroup

Tags: html, css, jquery-chosen

I have a multi select list, where first optgroup is empty (does not have child options) by default chosen hides this group, but i still want to show it. is there a method to force chosen to not hide it? Refer to image we can see option group with label Main is not in the list.

[image: This is how chosen select list looks like]

```js
$('.chosen-control').chosen({ width: 400 });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <select multiple class="chosen-control">
            <optgroup label="Main"></optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Group A">
                <option>Option A1</option>
                <option>Option A2</option>
                <option>Option A3</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Group B">
                <option>Option B1</option>
                <option>Option B2</option>
                <option>Option B3</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Group C">
                <option>Option C1</option>
                <option>Option C2</option>
            </optgroup>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome.  Your question would get better / higher quality answers if you would include an [mcve].

Comment: Take a look at the following -> https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/2020#issuecomment-223768441; may still apply even though it is old thread

Comment: @Morpheus i have been reviewed that post that did not help, also i updated the question

Comment: @cale_b i added the example, and thanks for suggesting me

Comment: Is there a way to always show an empty `optgroup`, even when user types some chars in the Chosen input field?